# Does CancellationToken::cancel wait for tasks to finish or does it 'cancel' - 'kill' them

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm having a bit of a debate with colleagues.  Look at this code below:

```
    async fn terminate(token: CancellationToken, name: String) -> Result<()> {
        let mut sigterm = signal(SignalKind::terminate())?;
        let mut sigint = signal(SignalKind::interrupt())?;
        tokio::select! {
            _ = sigterm.recv() => { info!("Received SIGTERM, stopping service on {}", name); },
            _ = sigint.recv() => { info!("Received SIGINT, stopping service on {}", name); },
        }
        token.cancel();
        Ok(())
    }
```

Does token.cancel() wait for the tasks to finish?  Will it allow new tasks to come in?

Comment: I'm assuming this [`CancellationToken`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/sync/struct.CancellationToken.html) is from tokio-util?

Comment: *"Does token.cancel() wait for the tasks to finish?"* - what tasks? It won't affect the `sigterm` / `sigint` code above if that's what you're asking.

Comment: *"Will it allow new tasks to come in?"* - it kinda sounds like you're expecting `.cancel()` to do more than what it actually does, it only signals that the `token` is cancelled so that other code checking `.is_cancelled()` or waiting for `.cancelled()` will see the cancellation.

Comment: I see.  That is kind of what I am looking for - exactly what does `cancel` do.  This is a grpc server so when requests come in from the grpc connection they are spun off as new tokio tasks.  So `cancel` does not actually cancel the tasks?  It just sets a flag somewhere that can be checked with `is_cancelled`?

Comment: You can read the documentation and examples therein I linked in my first comment. It is not automagically associated with any tasks, and must be checked manually somewhere. It sounds like you're more interested in the [Graceful Shutdown tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/topics/shutdown) from tokio.